# imread returns None on some images but not others in the same folder

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, imread

I have been trying to read jpeg images with `imread` from `cv2` package. So far, other than this seemingly random selection of images to read, it has been great.

The problem is that, since I keep all of my images from the same source in the same folder, apparently `imread` worked on several images but not others for no obvious reason. I have closely inspected and made sure all images are working fine, of the same type, etc. However, as in the screenshots I attach below, only the selected images returned reasonable results whereas all others returned `None`. The exact code I used here is:

```
img = cv2.imread(image,1) #most None
```

Could anyone kindly suggest what possibly went wrong? Many thanks!
[image: Files1]

[image: Files2]

[image: Files3]
My codes as a whole:

```
images = os.listdir(os.path.join(input_dir, folder))
os.chdir(os.path.join(input_dir, folder))
#index += 1
index_array = []
out = []

# a quick recursion of summing up nested lists
rec = lambda x: sum(map(rec, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x

minLineLength = 20 ##? how to set these?
maxLineGap = 5 ##? how to set these?    

for image in images:
    print(image)
    if image == ".DS_Store" or (not image.endswith(".jpeg")):
        continue

    else:
         img = cv2.imread(image,1) 
#cv2.cv.LoadImage(image,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)## #Opening image
         if img is None:
            print("None")
            continue
         elif img is not None:
            print("Pppppppppaaaaaaaaaaassssssssss!")
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
            edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 120); 
            nedges = rec(edges.tolist())/255.0; 
            lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
            if lines is None:
                nlines = 0
            elif lines is not None:
                nlines = lines.shape[0]

            img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
            cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img_blur, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 120, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
            if circles is None:
                ncircles = 0
            elif circles is not None:
                circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
                ncircles = circles.shape[1]

            gray_blur = cv2.normalize(img_blur, img_blur, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
            ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_blur, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            square_cnts = []
            thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
            tmpimage, contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            #print("D")
            cnt0 = contours[0]
            tmp_h = h[::-1]
            appr = []
            npoly = []
            for index, cnt in enumerate(contours[::-1]):
                approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.1*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
                if approx is None:
                    continue
                elif approx is not None:
                    appr.append(approx)
                    npoly.append(len(approx))
            new = [nedges, nlines, ncircles, sum(npoly)*1.0/len(npoly)]
            out.append(new) #Adding new image to array shape of (x, 3, 100, 100) where x is image number
            index_array.append(image)
```

Comment: `imread` typically returns a `None` if `image` is an invalid file name. Please show how it is initialized.

Comment: @DyZ, thanks! How may I show its initialization? I scraped the images from http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/

Comment: You must have a loop somewhere in your program, I assume. Include it in your code.

Comment: Maybe your scraping didn't grab the images correctly. Try looking at them with some image viewers - GIMP, `feh`, etc

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks but my pics look fine when opened with apps...

Comment: Maybe share one that works, and more importantly, one that doesn't.